# BytesIO object casted into TextIOWrapper does not have fileno attribute.

Tags: python, io

I have the following code:

```
>>> import io
>>> b = io.BytesIO(b"Hello World")
>>> f = io.TextIOWrapper(b)
>>> f.fileno()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

However, when I load a file in, there is a `fileno` attribute:

```
>>> f = open("test.py")
>>> f.fileno()
3
```

Is there a way to create a `fileno` attribute for the first case, where I am casting a `BytesIO` object to the `TextIOWrapper` object?

Answer (score 3):

Well, `fileno` is not available because *there is no file*.

The `fileno()` method returns an integer, representing the position of an open file in the operating system's table of process-related files. If you don't *actually open* a file, the operating system won't give you a file number.

Your program's standard input, output and error streams (those you read with `input` and write with `print`) are numbered `0`, `1` and `2`. Subsequent open files are usually given sequential numbers by the system.

This cannot be faked reliably: anything you return from `fileno()` when no actual file is backing the object is a lie. This is why the implementation chose to raise `UnsupportedOperation`. No return makes sense, except perhaps `None`.

If it's absolutely imperative that you have a `fileno()` for your string content, you could do this:

- Open a file for `read+write`
- Write your string
- Rewind the file to the beginning

There must be a better design, however, that won't force you to use this workaround.