# Why is this Popen call returning a "io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno" error in Django 2.0?

Tags: python, django, gulp, subprocess

I recently upgraded my project to Django 2.0, and an error started cropping up. First off, I use `django_gulp` to start a gulp process whenever I start the django runserver. I'm using the [`runserver_plus` branch of the `django_gulp` project](https://github.com/beaugunderson/django-gulp/tree/runserver-plus). Here's [the relevant code snippet](https://github.com/beaugunderson/django-gulp/blob/runserver-plus/django_gulp/management/commands/runserver_plus.py#L87) from the `django_gulp` project, where it makes the `subprocess.Popen` call. This call was functioning correctly in Django 1.11.x.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import atexit
import os
import psutil
import subprocess
import sys
import traceback

from signal import SIGTERM

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

from django.core.management.base import CommandError
from django.conf import settings

from django_extensions.management.commands.runserver_plus import Command \
    as DjangoExtensionsRunserverCommand

from env_tools import load_env


class Command(DjangoExtensionsRunserverCommand):
    """
    Subclass the RunserverCommand from Staticfiles to set up our gulp
    environment.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cleanup_closing = False
        self.gulp_process = None

        super(Command, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def gulp_exited_cb(future):
        if future.exception():
            print(traceback.format_exc())

            children = psutil.Process().children(recursive=True)

            for child in children:
                print('>>> Killing pid {}'.format(child.pid))

                child.send_signal(SIGTERM)

            print('>>> Exiting')

            # It would be nice to be able to raise a CommandError or use
            # sys.kill here but neither of those stop the runserver instance
            # since we're in a thread. This method is used in django as well.
            os._exit(1)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            env = load_env()
        except IOError:
            env = {}

        # XXX: In Django 1.8 this changes to:
        # if 'PORT' in env and not options.get('addrport'):
        #     options['addrport'] = env['PORT']

        if 'PORT' in env and not args:
            args = (env['PORT'],)

        # We're subclassing runserver, which spawns threads for its
        # autoreloader with RUN_MAIN set to true, we have to check for
        # this to avoid running gulp twice.
        if not os.getenv('RUN_MAIN', False):
            pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

            gulp_thread = pool.submit(self.start_gulp)
            gulp_thread.add_done_callback(self.gulp_exited_cb)

        return super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)

    def kill_gulp_process(self):
        if self.gulp_process.returncode is not None:
            return

        self.cleanup_closing = True
        self.stdout.write('>>> Closing gulp process')

        self.gulp_process.terminate()

    def start_gulp(self):
        self.stdout.write('>>> Starting gulp')

        gulp_command = getattr(settings, 'GULP_DEVELOP_COMMAND', 'gulp')

        self.gulp_process = subprocess.Popen(
            [gulp_command],
            shell=True,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=self.stdout,
            stderr=self.stderr)

        if self.gulp_process.poll() is not None:
            raise CommandError('gulp failed to start')

        self.stdout.write('>>> gulp process on pid {0}'
                          .format(self.gulp_process.pid))

        atexit.register(self.kill_gulp_process)

        self.gulp_process.wait()

        if self.gulp_process.returncode != 0 and not self.cleanup_closing:
            raise CommandError('gulp exited unexpectedly')
```

Notice that `self.stdout` and `self.stderr`, the arguments to `subprocess.Popen`, are references to [`django.core.management.base.OutputWrapper`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.0.x/django/core/management/base.py#L75). All I can say so far is that Django 1.11's `OutputWrapper` class inherited from `object`, and Django 2.0's `OutputWrapper` class inherits from `TextIOBase`.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 667, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1184, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

If this is a `django_gulp` issue, I'll create an issue and/or PR within that repo that fixes this. But, for now, I'd like to get this working within my own project.

I should also mention that I am running this in a docker-compose environment, so maybe something with that is causing the error. I have not tested this on a non-Docker environment yet.

### Edit

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791095/690573), it appears the subprocess code may be assuming that the stream has a file descriptor, where in this case there isn't one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing this error is that file-like objects are a Python abstraction. The operating system and other processes don't know about this abstraction, they only know about file descriptors. Therefore you *must* pass a valid file descriptor to Popen.

You can access the stream wrapped by `OutputWrapper` from `_out`:

```
self.gulp_process = subprocess.Popen(
    #...
    stdout=self.stdout._out,
    stderr=self.stderr._out)
```

Or, you can just pass the standard file numbers for standard output and error:

```
self.gulp_process = subprocess.Popen(
    #...
    stdout=1,
    stderr=2)
```