# Is it possible to add raw bytes to a TarFile object in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tarfile

I'm creating a Python script that does a backup of various files, and data on my server.

It looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import tarfile
import os

DIRS_TO_BACKUP = []
FILES_TO_BACKUP = []
backup_destination = "/tmp/out.tar.gz"

# Code that adds directories to DIRS_TO_BACKUP
DIRS_TO_BACKUP.append("/opt/PROJECT_DIR/...")

# Code that adds files to FILES_TO_BACKUP
FILES_TO_BACKUP.append("/etc/SOME_FILE")

# Code to backup my database
db_table = subprocess.run(['mysqldump', 'my_database'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout

with tarfile.open(backup_destination, "w:gz") as tar:
    for DIR in DIRS_TO_BACKUP:
        tar.add(DIR, arcname=os.path.basename(DIR))

    for FILE in FILES_TO_BACKUP:
        tar.add(FILE, arcname=os.path.basename(FILE))

    # Code to save db_table (<class 'bytes'>) to tar somehow
```

Here, db_table are the raw bytes that represent my database. I want to give this data a filename, and save it in my output tar.gz file as a regular file. Is this possible without first saving db_table to the filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me adding an image that was extracted as a String Tensor inside a TFRecord (no extra intermediate file needs to be saved)

```
 with tarfile.open('image.tar.gz', 'w:gz') as tar:
  for img, filename, *_ in tqdm(ds.take(5)):    # save 5 for testing
    fname = filename.numpy().decode('utf-8')
    
    img = tf.io.encode_jpeg(img, quality=100)
    img_fileobj = BytesIO(img.numpy())

    tarinfo = tarfile.TarInfo(name=fname)
    tarinfo.size = img_fileobj.getbuffer().nbytes
    
    tar.addfile(tarinfo, img_fileobj)
```

Comment: excuse me for not following the code context in the question. But you can figure out the idea.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the tarfile docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html, you can add a file object to a tar using `gettarinfo` and `addfile`. Just convert your bytes to a file object using `io.BytesIO`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import tarfile
import os
import io

DIRS_TO_BACKUP = []
FILES_TO_BACKUP = []
backup_destination = "/tmp/out.tar.gz"

# Code that adds directories to DIRS_TO_BACKUP
DIRS_TO_BACKUP.append("/opt/PROJECT_DIR/...")

# Code that adds files to FILES_TO_BACKUP
FILES_TO_BACKUP.append("/etc/SOME_FILE")

# Code to backup my database
db_table = subprocess.run(['mysqldump', 'my_database'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
db_fileobj = io.BytesIO(db_table)

with tarfile.open(backup_destination, "w:gz") as tar:
    for DIR in DIRS_TO_BACKUP:
        tar.add(DIR, arcname=os.path.basename(DIR))

    for FILE in FILES_TO_BACKUP:
        tar.add(FILE, arcname=os.path.basename(FILE))

    # Code to save db_table (<class 'bytes'>) to tar somehow
    db_info = tar.gettarinfo(name="database", arcname="database", fileobj=db_fileobj)
    tar.addfile(db_info, fileobj=db_fileobj)
```

Comment: Not quite working. The `tar.gettarinfo()` call is throwing the exception: `AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'name'`. It sounds like it has a problem with the `io.BytesIO` object not having a filename. Adding `db_fileobj.name = "something"` fixes that, but throws a different exception: `io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno`. Sounds like there's no simple fix for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791095/6423456. Also note that for `tar.getattrinfo`, it sounds like if we're supplying the `fileobj` arg, we don't need the `name` arg, according to the python docs. Any other ideas?

Comment: Perhaps instead of using `tar.gettarinfo()` to build the `TarInfo` object for us, we build it ourselves. Instantiate the class, and use `TarInfo.frombuf`? I'm just not sure what to enter for the `encoding` and `errors` args. Is `encoding` the source encoding it's expecting, or the output encoding it will write? There is no source encoding - it's raw bytes. What do I do for the `errors` arg? The docs don't seem to say anything about the `errors` arg at all.

Comment: @John I think your idea of building TarInfo is correct, i posted a solution for that.